# Toyota Corolla spring sound when braking

Tags: corolla, break

My Toyota Corolla is making the weirdest sound when braking (not squeaking). You can see the video on this link: https://photos.app.goo.gl/ylg43UksyJUS4pRj1

Now, I just went to Kal Tire, they did some work on my brake pads and rotors, charged me $700 for the service and the noise is still there.
I thought it was kind of weird since a problem on the rotors would me make more of a squeaking sound rather then the noise my car is making, right?

What is the problem? How can I diagnose it?

Comment: Is it coming from the rear? Do you have drum brakes?

Comment: $700?? I hope you got all brand new rotors, pads, lines, fluid, etc., for that price!

Comment: Hey @Ben yes I am pretty sure they are drum brakes. Which would make sense, right? that "spring" like noise

Comment: That’s what it sounds like to me. It’s hard to tell from the video but that’s the kind of noise you hear when drum brakes aren’t adjusted correctly or theres a broken spring. Might want to take a look at em.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a couple things...

1. Your new rotors could be warped. Although this isn't common, there is a chance.
2. Your caliper could be loose- its possible the mechanic didn't torque your calipers to spec, which is creating the weird noise you are getting.

Honestly, I would just bring the car back to where it was serviced and get it looked at. They should be able to diagnose pretty quickly.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for your response man. I will do some googling around those. I really didn't want to go to Kal "blind" again  and they charge me another $700 to not solve the problem